# How to create a design that uses specific % of DFF and LUT count in FPGA to measure power dissipation?

Tags: fpga, power-dissipation

I want to create a design which does not perform any specific useful function but utilizes specified amount of logic resource in the FPGA e.g 50% DFF and LUT or 50% DFF and 25% LUT e.t.c. I shall then perform power measurement across the different rails with and without PLL e.t.c.

Is there a practical way to do this? I need to take measurement across several FPGA families and compare them across three vendors.

Comment: You're really asking how to design a logic circuit within an FPGA. That'll normally be in VHDL, Verilog or (yuk) schematic form. Explaining how to design in those is far beyond the scope of a Q&A site. Your easiest route may be to download simple pre-existing VHDL firmware and synthesize that for each of your FPGAs. But you've got a big learning curve ahead of you.

Comment: Isn't this kind of like trying to determine power dissipation of an MCU based on the architecture without paying attention to the code it is running? (i.e. not accurate).

Comment: See I know plenty of VHDL. I created a basic design with a long shift register that uses 80% of the device logic but not LUTs. I measured the voltage drop across the sense resistor using my portable DMM. It just went from 1.5mV to 1.6mV. I did not understand what I am doing wrong. I had expected to be able to measure 100mW or more of power dissipation on the core voltage rail. I had wrongly assumed that there was industry standard method to measuring % logic used vs power dissipation for FPGAs like we have methods to measure processor performance and benchmark it.

Comment: surely you could just create *anything* and then duplicate it a bunch of times until you hit your target?

Comment: The "anything" has to compile if I just copy it many times. It is not so simple in hierarchical designs with large pinout. I create a large chain of shift registers that occupied 80% of the register count. But, I got negligible power dissipation as far as the voltage across sense resistor is concerned. I am really confused.

Comment: From your note about being confused, are you saying you know 'plenty of VHDL' but much less about the electronics it builds?

Answer (score 2):

FPGA vendors have some Excel files to make a preliminary power analysis. They give a rough idea.

Here link to the following files:

- **Xilinx**: https://www.xilinx.com/products/technology/power/xpe.html
- **Intel**: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/support/support-resources/operation-and-testing/power/pow-powerplay.html
- **Microsemi**: https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/design-resources/1748-power-calculator

FPGA power consumption has a static and a dynamic component.

About designs to test power:

One stupid design is a chain of inverters: Here you can fill LUTs and FFs and steer them on IOs. You need attributes so the not of the not of the not... is not optimized away by the synthesis tool. (ie DONT_TOUCH attribute described in the Xilinx Vivado Design Suite User Guide - UG901)

If want to include RAM and DSPs to the power estimation, generate a kind of stupid pseudo noise generator. The random bits stored in RAM blocks and their outputs filtered by a long   FIR using all FPGA multipliers.

This gives a VHDL design possible to port from one device to another but time spending to create the first code.

It is also good to know that some devices need a lot of PC memory to compile the design. (https://www.xilinx.com/products/design-tools/vivado/memory.html)

Comment: The directives bit is very nondescript but the answer relies upon it. What sort of directives? Please can you edit your answer and show an actual example of what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

The power consumption is not going to be a strong function of the **number** of LUTs and FFs used. What will have a large influence on power consumption is the **activity level** of the logic and flip-flops, and this is highly dependent on the specific design that is implemented in the FPGA. If you use a design that "does not perform any specific useful function" then it probably won't use nearly as much power as a design that represents a real application.

In other words, I think you need to reconsider your whole approach. But, if you want to press forward, then the way to hit a certain target usage of resources is probably by trial and error.